# In bash: Filter, sort by date in name, and return the most recently dated name

Tags: linux, bash, sort

In bash, I want to filter the list of file names to .csv only, sort according to date order (the date in the name, not the timestamp), and then return the most recent file name based on date order in the name:

```
[root@server test2]# curl -l "ftp.fakeurl.com.au/In Stock Daily CSV/"  --user username:password
InStockDaily01.07.19.csv
InStockDaily01.07.19.xls
InStockDaily02.07.19.csv
InStockDaily02.07.19.xls
InStockDaily03.06.19.csv
InStockDaily03.06.19.xls
InStockDaily03.07.19.csv
InStockDaily03.07.19.xls
InStockDaily04.06.19.csv
InStockDaily04.06.19.xls
InStockDaily04.07.19.csv
InStockDaily04.07.19.xls
InStockDaily05.06.19.csv
InStockDaily05.06.19.xls
InStockDaily05.07.19.csv
InStockDaily05.07.19.xls
InStockDaily06.06.19.csv
InStockDaily06.06.19.xls
InStockDaily07.06.19.csv
InStockDaily07.06.19.xls
InStockDaily08.07.19.csv
InStockDaily08.07.19.xlsx
InStockDaily09.07.19.csv
InStockDaily09.07.19.xls
InStockDaily10.07.19.csv
InStockDaily10.07.19.xls
InStockDaily11.06.19.csv
```

Comment: next time use ISO8601 date format instead of little-endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl -l "ftp.fakeurl.com.au/In Stock Daily CSV/"  --user username:password |
  grep '\.csv$' |
  sort -t. -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1 |
  tail -n 1
```

- `grep '\.csv$'` get the csv lines
- `sort -t. -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1` sort using the `.` as field separator by 3rd field year, 2nd field month and 1st field `InStockDailyXX` with the day
- `tail -n 1` get the last line (newest date)

Comment: Thanks, it works - could you kindly indulge a novice so as to explain the `sort -t. -k3,3 -k2,2 -k1,1` notation/structure?  I've never seen that before, thanks.

Comment: The `-t.` splits the line into 4 fields by `.` (default is the space or the tab character) and with `-k startpos[,endpos]` you can set the start and optional end position of the field (it's called _key_ in the manual). Obviously if no key is given the whole line is used as key. See the [online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html), there are a few examples.

Comment: I thank you for the kind explanation, the reference link, and the answer.

Comment: (Re: your previous comment) Note that the default separator is the transition from a non-blank to a blank (not limited to space and tab)

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh`, you can get the sorted list of `csv`s with:

```
list=(*.csv(oe'<REPLY=${(j::)${(s:.:Oa)REPLY}}>'))
```

And then the latest one is in `$list[-1]`

- `*.csv(glob-qualifier)`: glob with glob qualifiers
- `oe'<code>'`: `o`rder the list based on the `e`valuation of the `code` (where the code sets the `$REPLY` variable as the basis for sorting)
- `${(s:.:Oa)REPLY}`: `s`split the `$REPLY` variable (which contains the filename to consider) on dot, and reverse `O`rder by `a`rray indice (reverse the list)
  `${(j::)list}`: join the elements of the list. So if `$REPLY` was initially `InStockDaily10.07.19.csv`, the new `$REPLY` which the glob will sort on is `csv1907InStockDaily10`.

That assumes the prefix is always the same as in your example. If not, you can use:

```
list=(*.csv(oe'<REPLY=${(j::)${(Oas:.:M)REPLY%??.??.??.*}}>'))
```

Where `%pattern` in combination with the `M` parameter expansion flag, extracts the suffix `M`atching the pattern from the end of `$REPLY` (so `$REPLY` will be `csv190710` instead of `csv1907InStockDaily10`).